# How do we import question data from SQL Server to QnA Maker?

Tags: sql-server, azure, bots

How do we setup [QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/overview/overview) using Azure SQL Server as its data source? Or how to import data from an Azure SQL Server table into QnA Maker?

I cannot find anything about it on the internet. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to Qna maker?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, but there is no direct import.

You can use the rest api,see [this quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/quickstarts/csharp#create-knowledge-base). For this you need to create a json document containing the questions and answers. You will however need some process that extracts the data from sql server and calls the api using that data.

The other option is to create an export from sql server to one of the [supported formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported), In this case I think best would be to export SQL data to txt or xlsx file, and import that directly using QnA maker.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your suggestion. But my client somehow wanted it specifically an MSSQL data source for the QnA. So when a user inquires, QnA will query its answers from an MSSQL data source, if there is a possible way. Or somehow refresh the answers with no other additional layer. I was thinking of MS Data Factory, hoping to get some good results today.

Comment: Data factory is for batch, not for interactive querying.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Add the moment you cannot have real integration. It is on the radar though: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/578689-qna-maker-api/suggestions/33977965-answers-that-reference-real-time-database